# Ms Word 2007: blue strokes instead of deleting, red underline of new text

Tags: microsoft-word

I think it can be some like a "modification mode" or similar, supporting teamwork on documents, but I never experienced this functionality.

What is it? What is its name? How can I revert back to the normal function?

Comment: I didn't include screenshot because 1) it is a company private document and 2) I think people knowing the phenomena can easily answer the question even without a screenshot. But if anybody asks me to insert one, I will do.

Comment: It's probably change tracking but without further information it's really difficult to say more. You can find it in review - track changes to switch on / off. For already tracked changes click review - accept - all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The document is set to `track changes`, and the formatting will be gone when the changes are approved or the functionality has been disabled.

You have not specified which version of word you are using so I cannot provide you the exact way to disable `track changes`.

Comment: It was word2007, but knowing the magic keyword "track changes" I could find easily the problem with google. :-) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

That's most probably caused by "Change tracking", you can finish this behaviour at review - track changes.

To accept all changes already tracked and remove lines go to review - accept - all.